# previewing a html code in window application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I m developing a .net window application. I have string which contains all the code to generate html. How can I preview in browser without saving.
I tried `Response.Write` and added the namespace `system.web` also. But it seems that it will only work in web application.

Comment: Please provide you code ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the WebBrowser component:

```
webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html><body>hello</body></html>";
```

Comment: I tried this but its showing an error.."an object reference is required for the non static field, method or property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740617/previewing-a-html-code-in-window-application/34740683?noredirect=1#comment57231122_34740683